# Add new rules to team during registration in Laravel Spark

Tags: laravel, validation, apache-spark, laravel-spark

I am currently wanting to modify some of the validation rules during registration on Laravel Spark. I have added a couple new inputs that I want to add to the model, but for some reason the validation is not being hit. Below is the code that I have in my `SparkServiceProvider`:

```
Spark::swap('CreateTeam@rules', function () {
            return [
                'name' => 'required|max:255',
                'city' => 'required|max:255',
                'state' => 'required|max:255',
            ];
        });

        Spark::swap('CreateTeam@validator', function ($user, array $data) {
            $validator = \Validator::make($data, Spark::call(static::class.'@rules'));

            $validator->sometimes('slug', 'required|alpha_dash|max:255|unique:teams,slug', function () {
                return Spark::teamsIdentifiedByPath();
            });

            $validator->after(function ($validator) use ($user) {
                $this->validateMaximumTeamsNotExceeded($validator, $user);
            });

            return $validator;
        });
```

I have also attempted to override the CreateTeam interface and then bind it in my AppServiceProvider but that hasn't worked either. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Using the `Spark::swap` method, I was able to replace the default `CreateUser@validator` method like so:

```php
Spark::swap('CreateUser@validator', function ($request) {
            /**
             * @var Validator $validator
             */
            $validator = $this->baseValidator($request);

            $validator->sometimes('team', 'required|max:255', function ($input) {
                return Spark::usesTeams() &&
                    Spark::onlyTeamPlans() &&
                    ! isset($input['invitation']);
            });

            $validator->sometimes(['city', 'state'], 'required|max:100', function ($input) {
                return Spark::usesTeams() &&
                    Spark::onlyTeamPlans() &&
                    ! isset($input['invitation']);
            });

            $validator->sometimes('team_slug', 'required|alpha_dash|max:255|unique:teams,slug', function ($input) {
                return Spark::usesTeams() &&
                    Spark::onlyTeamPlans() &&
                    Spark::teamsIdentifiedByPath() &&
                    ! isset($input['invitation']);
            });

            return $validator;
        });
```